# How to set text over element with background opacity 0.6?

Tags: html, css, opacity

```css
.c{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 18em;
    .backgroundDiv{
        background: url("/images/DSC8253.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center ;
        height: 20em;
        opacity: 0.6;
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         z-index: -1;
         
    }
}
.bigText{
    display: flex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 8em;
    top:2em;
}
```

```html
 <section class="c">
         <div class="backgroundDiv"></div>
         <div class="bigText">
             <p>Pilki-HUILKI</p>
             </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried using rbga() colour for the bg instead of opacity? Opacity will change the opacity of the text as well that's in the div, rbga() will only change the background.

Comment: @NathanielFlick this would work with a background image? Which property do you mean should be set with an rgba() value?

Comment: Are you using a preprocessor because that doesn't look like CSS. However, when I make it CSS the text is over the image OK. Could you describe what you want the outcome to look like?

Comment: rgba will set opacity for colot how it suppose to work with image? i use sass yes. there is a git folder with fuul code atm

Comment: @Corrl whoops I forgot there's an image there, not a color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here in css file you type like below ( just small change )

```
.c {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.backgroundDiv {
  background: url('/images/DSC8253.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 20em;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.bigText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

I use position **absolute** to make the text over the background then i use transform to make it to the center

Comment: is it a common practice? or just solution for my werid thing?:)

Comment: @DeanWinchester88 i work in my company and this way is very popular i recommended you

Comment: thanks.  looking to be junior FE.is there any cheat list used for common situations like template for hamburger menu,modal windows and so on? i'm learning building mobile first

Comment: Pos absolute takes the icon out of the document flow and thus it doesn't not get the same opacity applied to it like the bg gets (.6).

Comment: well or i mde i mistake or it desn't work as expected https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/mdMwBJq

Comment: hmm i just checked i i saw the text in the center, or you want you text is in the center of a big image right ?

Comment: yeah like this Pilki text in the center of image.would make sense

Comment: ok your code i think something went wrong so i use my code pen: you can check here: https://codepen.io/gia-an/pen/rNzwGQM

Comment: aha. i see u put text div INside BG div. and i was following how this guy was doing. https://youtu.be/M3qBpPw77qo?t=355 (@5.55) confused how did it work out for him